# Are there any words with a hard "C" preceeding an 'I' in words starting with "ci"?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

Are there any English words that are pronounced with a hard "keh" sound as their first syllable, and begin with the two letters 'ci' in their spelling?

I ask purely out of curiosity, since I was unable to find any examples.

Comment: Chiral is as close as i can think of.

Comment: The closest I can think of is the name *Ciaran* as an Anglicisation of the name *Ciarán* but it's a proper noun, and it's more common to either leave it in the original *Ciarán* or to Anglicise further to *Kiaran*.

Comment: Some people used to say *kinema*, back in the early days of film.  But they spelled it with a -k-.

Comment: Famous actor _Cillian Murphy_ starts with __k__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that the *OED* records through its paper supplements.